# Use Spotify iOS SDK in India

Tags: ios, spotify

I am creating an streaming app and want to use the Spotify iOS SDK for the streaming purpose. But, the services of Spotify are not available in India. I have the Spotify premium account (based in US). The development will be held in India.
My question is, can I use the Spotify iOS SDK in India using a US based premium account without any proxy network?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is: "*Can I use the Spotify iOS SDK in India using a US based premium account without any proxy network?*". Based on the fact that you're trying to create a streaming app, I'd think that the question you intended to ask is: "**Is it possible to enable users to stream Spotify music in India?**"

**My answer:**
I've just read [(parts) of the Developer terms](https://developer.spotify.com/developer-terms-of-use/#section-iii-licenses-and-permissions) of the Spotify SDK. One thing I noticed was:

> Streaming via the Spotify Platform shall only be made available to
>   subscribers to the Premium Spotify Service.

So if I'm right, it is only possible to stream Spotify's music if your users have a Premium Spotify account, which currently isn't available in India, all by there self. It is however possible to use the iOS SDK in India, but this will exclude the possibility to stream (preview-)audio for non-premium users.

Comment: i want to login via api,not with default UI Provide in ios SDK.

Comment: You're not the one who has asked the question right? But what I described above applies also to logins via the API.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it's the account's country and not the location of the user what is used to determine if a user can access Spotify. In other words, with a US Premium account you can use Spotify wherever you are in the world as long as you keep paying for the subscription. [Read more on this thread](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Accounts-and-Subscriptions/What-happens-to-spotify-premium-when-I-travel-between-countries/td-p/421338).

You should be able to use your account while developing your app. Of course, a user trying to create a Spotify account from India will see a "Spotify is not available in your country" message when trying to sign up, but users accessing from countries where Spotify is available won't have any problem in signing up and logging in to your app.

Answer (score 0):

Three simple steps:

1. Download any VPN app from App Store i.e., [VPN 24](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vpn-24-hotspot-vpn-for-iphone/id1171369916?mt=8).
2. Go to App store account, change your region and country to USA by filling any sample address.
3. Now search `Spotify Music` on App Store and Download it!

You'll have to keep VPN turned on while using Spotify otherwise it won't work.