# Spotify is not avaliable in my country? Can't I use their API?

Tags: api, spotify

I was unable to sign up on Spotify as it is not available in India. Does this mean, I can't use their API too?
Is there any other alternatives or similar service for music?

Comment: For iPhone Users: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54329165/5415898)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use VPN. I solved this issue with TunnelBear app. Using TunnelBear you can move your IP to another country and then you can do signup and login.
Also, with same credentials you can login to https://developer.spotify.com and use API.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Shweta ! will try this hack :D

Comment: Hi, @Shweta and @Kalpesh! Where you able to Spotify API like this? Also can we use it on our website and make it live in India?

Comment: @PrakharVerma I used VPN to create developer account. It worked.